# Google SMTP returns required authentication but it's done as an app password

Tags: smtp, airflow, smtp-auth

I am setting up `SMTP` service on `Airflow 2.1.2`.
I get this error which is quite obvious:

```
smtplib.SMTPSenderRefused: (530, b'5.7.0 Authentication Required. Learn more at\n5.7.0  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=WantAuthError w5sm3433302wra.87 - gsmtp'
```

But authentication is done, i am using an email that has 2 steps authentication, so I created an app password and I recognized the activity in google account security tab..

My setup is:

```
AIRFLOW__EMAIL__EMAIL_BACKEND   airflow.utils.email.send_email_smtp
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_HOST    smtp.gmail.com
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_MAIL_FROM   my email
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PASSWORD    my app pwd of 16 chars
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_PORT    587
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_SSL False
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_STARTTLS    True
AIRFLOW__SMTP__SMTP_USER    my email
```

I checked and there is no extra space or something like that neither in pwd or email.

Why is it returning required authentication when authentication is really done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why it is not working. But do you see:

`Fetching SMTP credentials from configuration variables will be deprecated in a future` warning? You should if your environment variables will be used.

If you do not see it, then you likely have `smtp_default` connection in the Connection database.

In Airflow 2 the authentication for SMTP has been brought to the same level as  other connections and rather than passing user/password via environment variable, they should be configured as login/password in the 'smtp_default' connection.

The variables should still work as fallback, but if you already have `smtp_default` connection created and has some login/password (even empty) configured, those will be used instead of the ENV vars.

In your case likely the solution will be to set login/password in the connection.

Comment: I do not see `Fetching SMTP credentials from configuration variables will be deprecated in a future` in the task logs neither in the scheduler logs.

I checked and doesn't exist any `smtp_default` connection in Airflow. Which type should be it? I do not see `SMTP` type when creating a new conn.  So I do not know which connection I have to create.

Comment: You can use HTTP type (any type will do for that and yes it is misleading). You could also have the connection set by environment variable or secret backend - then you would not see it in the DB

Comment: Setting up the connextion fixed it! Thanks!